# Update object with destructuring // reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

i want update this object(newBook) with destructuring

```
let newBook ={
   bookId:book._id,
   favorite:false,
}
let {favorite} = newBook
favorite = true
```

favorite need to be a reference newBook.favorite

i see we can update the original objet like that

```
let b = newBook
b.favorite = true
```

but with the destructuring not work, any idea?

Comment: `let {favorite} = newBook` is equivalent to `let favorite = newBook.favorite;`. It doesn't create any link between the variable and the object.

Comment: Destructuring assignment is not the same as Object property assignment.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have property references.

Comment: @Barmar, what does that mean? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Undefined_prop

Comment: @StackSlave It's not possible to create a variable that's an alias for an object property, so that when you do `variable = something;` it modifies the property.

Comment: That is true, unless it's a setter... but you used the very specific word `"references"`. Just got me confused for a second there.

Comment: okey, but try this code  let newBook = {person:[{name:'agus'},{name:'gus'}]}  let {person} = newBook and change the first name person[0].name = 'gus' and change the original object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassigning a variable, by itself, never has any side effects (outside of extremely unusual situations like with `arguments` and exported ES6 module bindings). If you have

```
someIdentifier = someExpression
```

that line alone won't change anything else about the code, except where `someIdentifier` is used later.

If you want to update the original object, the only real way is to assign to a property of the object, like you're doing with

```
b.favorite = true
```

or

```
newBook.favorite = true
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with destructuring. Assigning a property of an object to a new variable just doesn't carry over the reference from the parent object to the new variable.

Comment: okey, i see but i have a code like this let newBook = {person:[{name:'agus'},{name:'gus'}]} when destructuring let {person} the variable keep the reference and i can modify the original object person[0].name = 'gus'

Comment: That's because there, you're not reassigning an *identifier*, but you're mutating a *property of an object*. `person[0].name` is not an standalone identifier - `person` refers to an object, so assigning to `person.<anyProperty>` mutates the `person` object.

Comment: okey, I think I understood but not so much